# Razor Pay : verify_payment

Tags: razorpay

According to the Razor pay documentation, you after the payment with the Card/Wallet has been successful, you need to verify the payment.
[https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/quick-integration/][1]
"This is a mandatory step that allows you to confirm the authenticity of the details returned to the Checkout form for successful payments." 
The following python code has been given as sample:

```
import razorpay

client = razorpay.Client(auth = ('<key_id>', '<key_secret>'))
params_dict = {
    'razorpay_order_id': '12122',
    'razorpay_payment_id': '332',
    'razorpay_signature': '23233'
}
client.utility.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
```

But I don't see the client object doesn't have a member with name : utility.
I am not able to find any good working sample.
Please provide some help with this step.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I found on how to instantiate the utility class.
If you go to the definition of razorpay.Client in VSCode (F12), you can see that it imports the utility class.
[image: from . import resources, utility]

Now if you go to the   definition of utility class, you can see how it can be initiated.
[image]

Based on that, I came up with the following code. NOTE that verify_payment_signature() doesn't return any value. But if there is any problem, it will come as an exception. (Eg: Remove one parameter from input and execute again).

```
# Install from VSCode command line : >python -m pip install razorpay
import razorpay

# this is your account credentials got from the dash board
client = razorpay.Client(auth = ('rzp_test_xxx', 'yyy'))

# These values are got from Razor pay paymentUI response
params_dict = {
    'razorpay_order_id': 'order_xxx',
    'razorpay_payment_id': 'pay_yyy',
    'razorpay_signature': 'zzzzz'
}

try:
    util = razorpay.Utility(client)

    util.verify_payment_signature(params_dict)
    
except Exception as e:
    print("Unexpected error:", e)
```